# WPF ComboBox's SelectedIndex doesn't change after setting its IsTextSearchEnabled to false

Tags: wpf, combobox, autocomplete

Let's say I have a `ComboBox` named `comboBox`.

I want to disable `ComboBox`'s auto complete feature.

At first I thought that everything I need to do is setting its `IsTextSearchEnabled` to `false` as following

```
comboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;
```

But it seems doing this cause some unexpected side effects.

When `IsTextSearchEnabled = true` (which is default with combobox) if you try to set a value for `ComboBox`'s `Text`, the combobox will find corresponding index in its `ItemsSource` and update the its `SelectedIndex` accordingly.

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("1");
lst.Add("2");
lst.Add("3");
lst.Add("4");
lst.Add("5");
MessageBox.Show(comboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString()); // -1
comboBox.ItemsSource = lst;
comboBox.Text = "3";
MessageBox.Show(comboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString()); // 2
```

Now when I tried to set `IsTextSearchEnabled = false`, the `ComboBox`'s `SelectedIndex` doesn't get updated when its `Text` changes.

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("1");
lst.Add("2");
lst.Add("3");
lst.Add("4");
lst.Add("5");
MessageBox.Show(comboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString()); // -1
comboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;
comboBox.ItemsSource = lst;
comboBox.Text = "3";
MessageBox.Show(comboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString()); // -1
```

I wonder if there is a way to achieve both (i.e disabling Auto Complete feature and still have ComboBox update its SelectedIndex automatically when its Text is changed)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to reach it. In your case with strings it's enough to set not the `Text` property, but `SelectedValue`:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("1");
lst.Add("2");
lst.Add("3");
lst.Add("4");
lst.Add("5");
MessageBox.Show(comboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString()); // -1
comboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;
comboBox.ItemsSource = lst;
comboBox.SelectedValue = "3";
MessageBox.Show(comboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString()); // 2
```

If you have more complex data type as string, then you can set also `SelectedValuePath` or search it by yourself in `ItemsSource` in event handler for `TextInput` and set the ´SelectedItem´.